# User management via google login and custom sign-in. How to avoid conflicts when emails are the same?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-authentication, mern, google-signin

I'm working on my first MERN fullstack project (an e-commerce demo). I have almost finished the authentication part, but I am having doubts about how to manage the users who have the same registration email both through custom sign-in and google login on the MongoDB database.
While doing various researches, I noticed that one of the methods used is the following:

1- If the email of the user who logs in via google login is already saved in the database as the same user had already registered via traditional sign-up, a new user will not be created in the database, but with both methods of signing -in we will point to the same user already saved with that email.

2- If there are no users saved in the database with that email (as the user logged in for the first time with google login and did not first register traditionally), once the user logged in with google login, it will be saved to the database for the first time.

However, this method presents problems with regard to the second type of users mentioned above.
In fact, if we merge the accounts with the same email on the database, if the user logs in for the first time with google, no password will be saved on the database. Therefore, if the same user decides in the future to log in in the traditional way, he will not be able to do so because he will not be able to fill in the password field.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Usually sites with the "first Google login immediately creates an account" have 2 solutions to this problem:

- As part of the "immediately create an account", they directly ask the user to choose a password.
- Alternatively, their "Change password" section allows *creating* a password should there be none yet. Therefore the account is indeed passworld-less at the beginning, but the user can opt to add a password.

For the 2nd solution, there's the small problem that if the user loses access to their Google account and didn't set a password, they're locked out. Rare case which might not be worth looking out for. *And perhaps your Customer Service can still help them out.*

Comment: I hadn't actually thought of this good solution. Thank you very much!